# Replace all files in git repo with the files that are on local machine

Tags: git, heroku, github

I want my git repository to look exactly like I have it locally.

As in if I have A,B,C,D and E files in my git repository and on my local machine I have deleted A,B and C, leaving D and E. When I push I want to see only D and E in the repository. how can I do this please. Also can I do the same with on heroku ?

Answer (score 3):

Stage all changes, make a commit, and push.

```
git add -A
git status
git commit -m "Deleted A, B, C"
git push
```

Comment: I tried it thanks. Am actually trying to use this to drop heroku database and redo a syncdb. how do I do this. There are errors with my tables and I want to drop the whole database and start over?

Comment: Is this database in the repo? I don't use Heroku, but most likely the database is not stored in the repository, but on the Heroku server, and there is a separate database for your local case.   Note - if you're using django, you can just call 'python manage.py reset appname' to drop all tables for a django app.